# MaxRequestSize attribute not stopping request aspnet dotnet core 3

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have created a sample project in which i want to call a `post` request with a file, in my live version this is an action in which users upload a file, but in my example, i just return a result of `Created`.

When i add the attribute `RequestSizeLimit` and run this code on my website, files over 100MB are not uploaded and the call to this request fails.  However, if i run the project using a TestServerFixture (as i am running this for integration tests) then the method doesnt fail?

I have attached the code for the normal and test project to this issue, so you can download, restore the packages and just run the tests.

Click [here](https://gofile.io/?c=1qPCR7) to download files

As you will see the test called "should_return_bad_request_when_file_over_100_mb" which fails.

Here is the basics of the code.

FileController in the api site

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace UploadAFile.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class FileController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpPost("upload")]
        [RequestSizeLimit(105906176)] // 101 MB
        public IActionResult PostFile()
        {
            return Created(Request.GetDisplayUrl(), "Yes it worked!");
        }
    }
}
```

The test methods

```
using System.Net.Http;
using Xunit;

namespace Tests
{
    public class TestFileController
    {
        [Fact]
        public async void should_return_success_when_file_1_kb()
        {
            var fixture = new TestServerFixture();

            // get a file to upload
            var bytes = new byte[1024]; // 1 KB
            HttpContent bytesContent = new ByteArrayContent(bytes);

            // act
            var client = fixture.CreateClient();
            var formData = new MultipartFormDataContent();
            formData.Add(bytesContent, "bigfile.txt", "bigfile.txt");
            var response = await client.PostAsync("file/upload", formData);

            // assert
            Assert.Equal(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Created, response.StatusCode);
        }

        [Fact]
        public async void should_return_bad_request_when_file_over_100_mb()
        {
            var fixture = new TestServerFixture();

            // get a file to upload
            var bytes = new byte[106954752]; // 102 MB
            HttpContent bytesContent = new ByteArrayContent(bytes);

            // act
            var client = fixture.CreateClient();
            var formData = new MultipartFormDataContent();
            formData.Add(bytesContent, "bigfile.txt", "bigfile.txt");
            var response = await client.PostAsync("file/upload", formData);

            // assert
            Assert.Equal(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, response.StatusCode);
        }
    }
}
```

Here are the references in my test project

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>

    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="16.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="16.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.4.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.visualstudio" Version="2.4.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="coverlet.collector" Version="1.0.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\UploadAFile\UploadAFile.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Does anyone have any idea why the second test doesnt fail?  Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is by design that Test Server does not support RequestSizeLimit.

You could see the following log by running your testing project:

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.RequestSizeLimitFilter: Warning: A request body size limit could not be applied. This server does not support the IHttpRequestBodySizeFeature.

**UPDATE:**

Add the following code and then you could see the log:

```
var builder = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseContentRoot(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .ConfigureLogging(config =>
            {
                config.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Debug);
                config.AddConsole();
                config.AddDebug();
            })
            .UseTestServer()
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

Comment: Thank you very much, out of curiosity, where abouts did you see that message?

Comment: Hi @Gillardo,Please check my answer.

Comment: How are we supposed to test this type of config then?